# Как установить PyQt5 на Ubuntu 13?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pyqt5

Как установить `PyQt5` на Ubuntu 13?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А чем вам не понравился [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/288515/python-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-pyqt-5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-ubuntu-13)?

`sudo apt-get install pyqt5-dev-tools`

Answer (score 0):

Есть же официальный сайт производителя там и качай. Там run пакет. Только зачем тебе qt5? Он по большей части для смартфонов.

http://qt-project.org/downloads

`sudo bashcd ... #путь к файлуchmod +777sh ... #имя файла`